# Does AVG Outlook add-on scan drafts?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, avg-antivirus

I'm trying to figure out whether or not the AVG Outlook add-on scans drafts, but I can't find any documentation about this, or any kind of log which indicates when scans are being run.

Can anyone tell me if the add-on scans drafts, and where I could possibly see a log of scans to verify this?

Comment: AVG scans all emails.  It also has a tendency to corrupt those emails if its ever removed from your system.

Comment: You'l know AVG is working because the rest of your PC will slow to a crawl.